# Where firebase saving all device tokens internally in their cloud?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Does firebase saving my app users device token on its own Realtime DB?
Is there any limit for sending device token to FCM?

I'm using Spark Plan (Free). I'm sending push from firebase console for entire app users by selecting bundle id. But APNS need device tokens. How
firebase managing all users device token?

Answer (score 3):

There is no public API that allows you to get a list of all FCM tokens in your project. FCM tokens are also not automatically stored in your project's realtime database or in another place where you can access them.

If you need the tokens in the database, you will need to store them there yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any limit for saving my app’s users device tokens in FCM under Spark Plan?

Comment: The free quota are documented on the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/). As long as you stay within those quotas, and within the terms-of-service, there is no other limit.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below on your Main Activity. The newToken will print on Log.

```
// get FCM token
            FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                    String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
                    Log.d("newToken",newToken);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Sorry dear, i'm not asking from mobile application perspective.